# How to remove files inside a container using the Docker API

Tags: rest, api, docker, docker-api

Please advise, how to remove files inside a container using the Docker API?
I have tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://192.168.1.55:5555/containers/{id}/exec' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "Cmd": [
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "'rm -rf /files/*'"
    ]
}'
```

Comment: You don’t: at the Docker API level you can’t access individual files, only whole containers, images, and volumes.  Trying to manipulate container filesystems as you’re showing isn’t usually a best practice either, nor is making the Docker API network-accessible.

Comment: "To exec a command in a container, you first need to create an exec instance, then start it. These two API endpoints are wrapped up in a single command-line command, docker exec.". In this way, after getting the response you must run new POST request ```/exec/{id}/start```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Docker API doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#tag/Exec) "To exec a command in a container, you first need to create an exec instance, then start it. These two API endpoints are wrapped up in a single command-line command, docker exec." In this way, after getting the response you must run new POST request `/exec/{id}/start`